# Need help querying Oracle date field

Tags: sql, oracle

Confused on why this happens. I have a query that is excluding records that I want to include.

The record in question has these values:

```
MEMBER_ID            NAME_FIRST           NAME_LAST                      START_DATE END_DATE  PROGRAM_ID INDICATOR               
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------------------ ---------- --------- ---------- -------------------------
M########            BOB                  JOHN                           01-FEB-10  30-APR-14 M90        plan
```

(changed values slightly to preserve HIPPA compliance).

So the end date is clearly 30-APR-14.

And yet when I run this SQL, the record does NOT come back:

```
SELECT 
  HNO.MEMBER_ID,
  HNAME.NAME_FIRST,
  HNAME.NAME_LAST,
  HDATE.START_DATE,
  HDATE.END_DATE,
  HNAME.PROGRAM_ID,
  HDATE.INDICATOR
FROM HCFA_NAME_ORG HNO
INNER JOIN NAME HNAME
ON HNO.NAME_ID = HNAME.NAME_ID
INNER JOIN HCFA_DATE HDATE
ON HNO.NAME_ID = HDATE.NAME_ID
WHERE INSTR(HNO.MEMBER_ID,'M',1,1)>0 AND
MEMBER_ID='M20012289' and INDICATOR='plan' AND
HDATE.START_DATE <=  LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2)) AND  
  HNAME.PROGRAM_ID != 'XXX'
  AND (HDATE.END_DATE IS NULL OR HDATE.END_DATE>=LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2)))
```

When I comment out the last line, it does come back:

Why is this? The value is clearly =LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2)) So why does this get excluded? Maybe I am not understanding something about Oracle date fields or how to properly query them.

Comment: The Oracle date might have a time component associated to it.

Comment: Try doing a SELECT TO_CHAR(END_Date, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SSxFF') and post what you find.

Comment: Today is the last day of June where I am sitting, but in other parts of the world, it is already July 1st.  You should also check the value of `sysdate` on the computer where you are running this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Trunc() function to truncate the time associated with the date. Then only the dates can be compared as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As cdummy has answered, the TRUNC function needs to be used, such that only the date parts are compared and the time parts are ignored for comparison.

```
AND TRUNC(HDATE.START_DATE) <= TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2)))
AND HNAME.PROGRAM_ID != 'XXX'
AND (HDATE.END_DATE IS NULL OR TRUNC(HDATE.END_DATE) >= TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2))));
```

Also, you can check the time parts of START_DATE and END_DATE, by querying as below:

```
SELECT 
  TO_CHAR(HDATE.START_DATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'),
  TO_CHAR(HDATE.END_DATE,, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM HCFA_NAME_ORG HNO
INNER JOIN NAME HNAME
ON HNO.NAME_ID = HNAME.NAME_ID
INNER JOIN HCFA_DATE HDATE
ON HNO.NAME_ID = HDATE.NAME_ID
WHERE INSTR(HNO.MEMBER_ID,'M',1,1) > 0 
AND MEMBER_ID='M20012289' 
AND INDICATOR='plan' 
AND HNAME.PROGRAM_ID != 'XXX';
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line, looks as :

```
AND (HDATE.END_DATE IS NULL OR HDATE.END_DATE>=LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2)))

30-APR-14-00.00:00 >= 30-JUN-14-09.xx:xx (it includes the time part),
```

therefore it returns FALSE and you don't get the record.

To truncates the time part use TRUNC() function:

```
AND (HDATE.END_DATE IS NULL OR HDATE.END_DATE>=TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2))))
```

Just a small hint that there are months with 31 days :)